# zsh use old binary after install new binary

Tags: linux, centos, curl, zsh

I've upgraded curl from source by `configure`, `make` and `sudo make install`.
But, My zsh use old version binary. What the reason for this behavior?

#### Environment

- CentOS Linux release 7.8.2003
- zsh 5.3.1
- antigen

#### Processes

1. Install curl 7.75
2. `curl --version` run old version(7.29)
3. `/usr/local/bin/curl --version` run new version(7.75)

```
$ curl --version
curl 7.29.0 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)  (snip)

$ which curl
/usr/local/bin/curl

$ /usr/local/bin/curl --version
curl 7.75.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)  (snip)
```

If I'll write `PATH` environment variable without change, zsh run new version without absolute path.

```
$ curl --version
curl 7.29.0 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)  (snip)

$ export PATH=$PATH

$ curl --version
curl 7.75.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)  (snip)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run the `rehash` command to make `zsh` pick up the new command location. `zsh` caches the locations of commands internally so that it doesn't have to traverse the `$PATH` every time. The `rehash` command refreshes that cache.